# Getting NumberFormat while trying to parse a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse a string to an integer. The string is a number when I do sys out but when I try to parse it then it adds a double quote at the beginning. I'm not doing anything additional.

Following is a snippet of my code:

```
System.out.println("Result 2 is: "+results[2]);
String temp = results[2].replace("\"", "");
System.out.println("String Temp is: "+temp);
int height = Integer.parseInt(results[1].replace("\"", ""));
int width = Integer.parseInt(results[2].replace("\"", ""));
```

**In the logs:**

String Temp is: 2550 
wt.system.err wcadmin - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2550

This exception is only for result[2]. Something to do with character set?

Comment: can you show the original values of the results array?

Comment: have you tried searching this problem ?

Comment: What is your results array? Please post that so it becomes easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Parse **`temp`**. Change

```
int width = Integer.parseInt(results[2].replace("\"", ""));
```

to

```
int width = Integer.parseInt(temp);
```

Option 2: Use a *regular expression* to remove everything not a digit instead of trying to handle corner cases by hand.

```
int width = Integer.parseInt(results[2].replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
```

Comment: Just curious what's wrong if I directly parse results[2].replace("\"", "")?

Comment: Can't tell. You haven't posted a MCVE.

Comment: Can you tell me what MCVE is?

Comment: Minimum complete verifiable example